# datatable with columGroup has issue in responsive mode

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am using Sentinel 2.1 and Primefaces 5.3, JSF 2.0, on Weblogic 11g.

We have production applications running on the above spec for a very long time now, and have no issues other than the below.

I have a datatable with col span and row span. The table looks fine in Desktop mode, but when seen in Responsive mode, the table looks very odd and a user cannot make sense out of this data table.

Xhtml

```
    <p:dataTable var="esl" value="#{estleaves.eleaves}" reflow="true"
                        >

                        <p:columnGroup type="header">
                            <p:row>
                                <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Employee" styleClass="Wid10"/>
                                <p:column colspan="4" headerText="Jan" />
                                <p:column colspan="4" headerText="Feb" />
                            </p:row>

        <p:row>
                                <p:column headerText="w1" styleClass="Fs9" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0" />
                                <p:column headerText="w2" styleClass="Fs9" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0" />
                                <p:column headerText="w3" styleClass="Fs9" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0" />
                                <p:column headerText="w4" styleClass="Fs9" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0" />

                                <p:column headerText="w1" styleClass="Fs9" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0" />
                                <p:column headerText="w2" styleClass="Fs9" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0" />
                                <p:column headerText="w3" styleClass="Fs9" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0" />
                                <p:column headerText="w4" styleClass="Fs9" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0" />
                            </p:row>
                        </p:columnGroup>
         <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="#{esl.empName}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column styleClass="Fs14"  >
                            <h:outputText value="#{esl.jan.w1}"  />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column styleClass="Fs14"  >
                            <h:outputText value="#{esl.jan.w2}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column styleClass="Fs14"  >
                            <h:outputText value="#{esl.jan.w3}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column styleClass="Fs14"  >
                            <h:outputText value="#{esl.jan.w4}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column styleClass="Fs14"  >
                            <h:outputText value="#{esl.feb.w1}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column styleClass="Fs14"  >
                            <h:outputText value="#{esl.feb.w2}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column styleClass="Fs14"  >
                            <h:outputText value="#{esl.feb.w3}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column styleClass="Fs14"  >
                            <h:outputText value="#{esl.feb.w4}"/>
                        </p:column>
```

Screenshot of Datatable on the Desktop Mode
[image]

Screenshot of Datatable on Responsive mode of iPhone pixel approx..
[image]

Comment: And keep in mind that not all combinations of features are tested/supported. And no, there is no multidimensional feature matrix. Not even a two dimensional one

Comment: Yes i tried with 6.0RC3, but the issue still remains.

Comment: How to show a datatable only if the screen resolution is of mobile size like 238×482 px. Basically i am thinking to show a different datatable developed specifically for mobile screen resolution. and i dont want this datatable to be shown if the mode is desktop. Any leads  ?

Comment: Sure... in an initial page, use some javascript to detect the screen resolution. Post this to the server and use that to decide to render A or B in the page...